# Systemctl daemon only works when verbose is enabled

Tags: systemd, daemon, systemctl, start-stop-daemon

I have a daemon in init.d which except for the name and description has exactly the same structure as the standard ubuntu [skeleton file](https://gist.github.com/mrowe/8b617a8b12a6248d48b8). When I try to run said daemon using

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mydaemon start
```

I get an error that starting the daemon failed with the message

```
Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

which isn't very helpful as code 1 doesn't really mean anything as far as I can tell. While debugging this, at one point I decided to change the verbose variable at /lib/init/vars.sh from no to yes, just to provoke some output and upon doing that, the daemon runs flawlessly. Yet when I change verbose back to no, I get the same errors as previously. Have any of you ever encountered somehthing like this and now what may be causing it?

Also, the daemon code is in c++ and is the following (although i don't think it's neccesarily relevant for this):

```cpp
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define DAEMON_NAME "mydaemon"

void process(){

    syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "Writing to log from Daemon");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    //Set our Logging Mask and open the Log
    setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_NOTICE));
    openlog(DAEMON_NAME, LOG_CONS | LOG_NDELAY | LOG_PERROR | LOG_PID, LOG_USER);

    pid_t pid, sid;

   //Fork the Parent Process
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //We got a good pid, Close the Parent Process
    if (pid > 0) { exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); }

    //Change File Mask
    umask(0);

    //Create a new Signature Id for our child
    sid = setsid();
    if (sid < 0) {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    // Change to root
    chdir("/");

    //Close File Descriptors
    int x;
    for (x = sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX); x>=0; x--)
    {
        close (x);
    }

    //----------------
    //Main Process
    //----------------
    while(true){
        process();    //Run our Process
        sleep(30); //Sleep for 30 seconds
        break;    
    }

    //Close the log
    closelog ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since this question is tagged systemd and systemctl, I'd like to point out that none of the `fork` and `setsid` boilerplate code is necessary if you configure your program to run as a systemd service (type=simple).

Comment: Thank you, that's good to know!